# use variable sum in a regular expression in bash

Tags: regex, expression

I want to write a script which able to select some sort of IP address

```
sum=153
for i in {1..5};
do
cat filename | egrep -o '^([0-9]{1,3}[.] ${sum + i}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}'
```

Filename contains sort of ip address. Output needs to be like this:

```
*.153.*.*
*.154.*.* 
*.155.*.*
*.156.*.*
```

But nothing selected by grep at all.

Comment: What is the input, and what is the output? give examples.

Comment: 10.150.2.3 10.152.2.5 10.153.2.5.10.155.20.22 10.153.20.23 10.153.30.10 10.158.33.4  10.160.11.20  10.142.20.12  10.142.20.11 and more .. in a one column

Comment: why `10.158.33.4` is missed from your output(as `153+5` gives `158`)?

Comment: nothing on output right now,, yes if regex going to work it will be display on output

Comment: nothing on output .. i want to select ip addresses which second octet start by 153, 154, 155 , ... countered by i

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
grep -Eo "^[0-9]{1,3}[.] $((sum + i))[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}" filename
```

The main points:

- Use double quotation marks around the grep pattern to allow variable expansion
- Use `$((sum + i))` to actually perform addition in Bash.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/0PBYju):

```
sum=152;
s="152. 152.012.123
153. 153.123.123";
grep -Eo "^[0-9]{1,3}[.] $((sum + i))[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}" <<< "$s"
# => 153. 153.123.123
```